# Is int(doubleValue) guaranteed to be smaller or equal to doubleValue for positive values

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, type-conversion

I know this should be avoided, but unfortunately I have to use integers and floating point (double) in a mixed calculation. The title already states the question:
Is the following code guaranteed to work (no assert) with all c++ floating point implementations regardless the numeric values as long as there is no overflow ?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the values are always positive

```
double realSplit = seg.squareLength() / sqr(maxLength);
int split = realSplit; 
assert(realSplit-split >= 0.0);
```

Comment: @netcoder: There is an implicit "cast", you could also write int split = int(realSplit), which would be the same but actually not a real cast as far as I get the meaning of the word cast right

Comment: It's implicit but there is loss of data so it is likely the compiler will warn you about it. Use a cast to make it go away. :)

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't, although I am quite strict about warnings. I'm using gcc (4.4.3) with -Wall -Wextra and some more irrelevant to this case. Which gcc option should warn about this ?

Comment: Ah I see what's happening. It's `-Wconversion`. I have it enabled by default. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting a floating-point value to an integer value discards the fractional part. For values greater than or equal to 0, your assert holds. For values less than 0 it goes the other way.

Comment: Exactly.  The standard reference is C++11, 4.9: "The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type."